# Generating a spanning set for $R^n$ with arbitrary vectors and a subset of standard basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

A longer problem boils down to determining if $ColA = R^n$ for a constructed matrix $A$.

This matrix will have columns from the set $\{w_1,..., w_i\}$ of $i$ arbitrary linearly independent vectors in $R^n$, where $1 \leq i \leq n$. To provide the $n-i$ remaining columns we are allowed only to take a subset of the standard basis vectors in $R^n$ (n-1 zero entries, 1 one). My question is the following: Is there always a choice of this subset that ensures a linearly independent set $\{w_1,...,w_i,v_1,...,v_{n-i}\}$ making the desired matrix attainable? How would I go about formally proving this?

Example: In lower dimensions it seems clear that this is the case. In $R^2$ a vector $w$ generating an arbitrary line is most certainly not a scaled version of both $e_1 = [1 \quad 0]^T$ and $e_2 = [0 \quad 1]^T$. So at least one of $\{e_1, e_2\}$ could form a $2 \times 2$ matrix with $w$, where $ColA = R^2$.

My thinking so far is this: Linear independence is equivalent to having one of the vectors in the set be a linear combination of the others. The system $[w_1 ... w_i | e_k]$ possibly has a solution with a coefficient vector in $R^i$ giving the weights to this linear dependence relation. Since the constructed $n \times i$ matrix does not have a column space equal to $R^n$, all standard basis vectors can not be attainable by some such coefficient vector. If it were, we would be spanning $R^n$, right?

So there is some $e_k \in R^n$, a standard basis that yields an inconsistent linear dependence relation. In fact, there must be at least $n-i$ such standard basis vectors, since inclusion of some independent $e_k$ into a new matrix that is $n \times (i+1)$ necessarily leads to the same argument that not all $n$ basis vectors are attainable. This induction continues in $n-i$ steps. Is this correct?

I'm sorry if this ends up being extremely trivial. I would really appreciate it if errors, better approaches etc. are pointed out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure about the proof, but I know how to pick the vectors to complete the spanning of $\Bbb{R}^n$.  First go through all the standard basis vectors and include pick any which is linearly independent from $\{ w_1,..., w_{n-i}\}$.  For any remaining vectors (if any) you can arbitrarily add standard basis vectors that are left.

Ex: 
$$\Bbb{R}^3,  w_1 = (1,1,0)$$

Add 
$$e_3 = (0,0,1)$$

And then arbitrarily add either $$e_1=(1,0,0)$$ or $$e_2=(0,1,0)$$

Comment: Yes @IanJ, that’s the process! It is intuitive in lower dimensions but I’m not sure if my generalization holds. I’m not sure about arbitrarily adding remaining standard basis vectors though. It seems to me that these would have to be checked for linear independence in relation to the already existing set.

Comment: Maybe try to do an induction proof with making the $w_i$ column vectors lower diagonal with column operations.  If you can do it then you only need to extend $w$ with the $n-i$ basis vectors to complete the diagonal.  If you can't do it, it means that $w$ doesn't span one of the $e_i$ dimensions, and that one needs to be added in.  Once you add in any required $e_i$ you should be able to make the matric lower diagonal by using column operations.  (None of the column operations should need to touch the $e_i$ that you add in).  How you do column operations on $w$ will dictate the $e_i$.